# Why does this CORS request to a google Drive Sheet fail in Firefox ? (works in Chrome)

Tags: ajax, firefox, google-drive-api, xmlhttprequest, cors

I'm trying to request a google sheet from the client in javascript, using jquery ajax.

The following code works in Chrome but fails in Firefox.

Question : how can I get it to work in Firefox?

If it's a server configuration issue then does this mean it's impossible to link to google drive documents from a firefox client?

Here is the code:

```
var url = 'http://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1-on_GfmvaEcOk7HcWfKb8B6KFRv166RkLN2YmDEtDn4&exportFormat=csv';
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'text',
    success : function(res, status){
        console.log('status : ' + status);
        console.log(res);
    },
    error : function(res, status, error){
        console.log('status : ' + status);
        console.log(res);
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

In Chrome I get a 307 response then a 200 with the desired data.
In Firefox I get a only a 200 response but with the error message something like "Access-Control-Allow-Origin header missing, Same Origin Policy does not allow to fetch this resource".

Comment: by the way, for anyone interested, I had described the workaround below using jsonp, but a genius stackoverflow mod deleted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround by configuring Google Drive slightly differently, and using JSONP :

1) In Google Drive, Publish on the web the document & set sharing options to Public

2) Export your data in JSON format with a JSON type link, it will look like : "http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/YOUR_FILE_ID/od6/public/values?alt=json&callback=myCallback". You need to append &callback=myCallback to use JSONP. You can use jQuery to make your JSONP call.

3) To use the data, you need to define the callback function specified in the url , in this case "myCallback"

I've mentioned a similar procedure in a different answer but I think it can be useful to mention it here as well since it directly relates to the problem I was facing.

@EnricoFerreguti you should replace YOUR_FILE_ID with your file ID. Example : https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1-on_GfmvaEcOk7HcWfKb8B6KFRv166RkLN2YmDEtDn4/od6/public/values?alt=json from the http://misterfresh.github.io/react-drive-cms/ website .

Comment: The solution appears interesting but the url provided returns an error page. Should you check it?

Comment: @Mister Fresh can you specify this answer?
I am fairly new to web development and don't know how to adapt your workaround

Comment: @EnricoFerreguti check https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1-on_GfmvaEcOk7HcWfKb8B6KFRv166RkLN2YmDEtDn4/od6/public/values?alt=json

Comment: @gustavz check http://misterfresh.github.io/react-drive-cms/  for an implementation example

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `docs.google.com` does not set CORS headers on redirects. And Chrome is not following the specification by not enforcing that and therefore has a security bug of sorts.

Comment: So what are my options if I want to use the contents of a google sheet in a webpage? Would switching the privacy settings from "anyone with a link" to "public on the web" help? Or would jsonp work?

Comment: Actually, it seems changing the link to be HTTPS might do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. Actually with https it fails also on Chrome. Will post a workaround I've come up with

Answer (score 2):

`docs.google.com` is in Chrome's HSTS preload list. The request to `http://docs.google.com` is transparently rewritten to `https://docs.google.com`, so no redirect happens.

I assume this will resolve itself if Firefox pulls an updated copy of the HSTS preload list. As Anne notes, simply changing the link to `https` directly will solve your use case.

Comment: https fails also on Chrome, I posted a workaround using jsonp