# body onload function call inside <td> tag not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

I am using an HTML table with a javascript function to fetch cell values from google published CSV sheet into my HTML table.

My HTML table screenshot
[image]

As you can see in my table screenshot, the cell values are not displaying correctly.

Because

**Test 1** should display value **10** (there's a function named `loadData()` for this)

**Test 2** should display value **20** (there's a function named `loadData2()` for this)

But right now it's only displaying **20** which is coming from the function named `loadData2()` for both **Test 1** and **Test 2** row.

Maybe my onload function call is not working properly.

Can you please recheck my code what's going wrong here? I am new to coding. I don't know how to fix it.

Here's my javascript code:

```js
function loadData() {
    console.log('loadData');
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRxRr2GAVpZAtGlpG3vQVDIwqjHjWq3z2Y-NQOf5Tu9IoEZDRQAQwevq8LSIXgwcql6EMyINFf04Dp2/pub?gid=0&single=true&range=B2&output=csv";
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}


function loadData2() {
    console.log('loadData2');
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRxRr2GAVpZAtGlpG3vQVDIwqjHjWq3z2Y-NQOf5Tu9IoEZDRQAQwevq8LSIXgwcql6EMyINFf04Dp2/pub?gid=0&single=true&range=B3&output=csv";
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function start() {
    loadData();
    loadData2();
}
```

My html code code:

```html
 <body onload="start()">
   <form name="Cpro">
      <table border="0" margin="0" padding="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tr height="20"px; style="border:0px;" >
            <td style="height:20px; width: 61.539px; background-color:#D6DCE4; border-top: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-bottom: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-right: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-left: solid 1px #8EA9DB; font-size: 16px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: left; ">Test 1</td>
            <td style="height:20px; width: 118.917px; background-color:#FFF2CC; border-top: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-bottom: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-right: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-left: solid 1px #8EA9DB; font-size: 16px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: right; ">
               <div id="display"></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr height=" 23.994px;" style="border:0px;" >
            <td style="height:20px; width: 61.539px; background-color:#D6DCE4; border-top: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-bottom: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-right: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-left: solid 1px #8EA9DB; font-size: 16px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: left; ">Test 2</td>
            <td style="height:20px; width: 118.917px; background-color:#FFF2CC; border-top: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-bottom: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-right: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-left: solid 1px #8EA9DB; font-size: 16px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: right; ">
               <div id="display2"></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr height=" 23.994px;" style="border:0px;" >
            <td style="height:20px; width: 61.539px; background-color:#D6DCE4; border-top: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-bottom: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-right: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-left: solid 1px #8EA9DB; font-size: 16px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: left; ">Test 3</td>
            <td style="height:20px; width: 118.917px; background-color:#FFF2CC; border-top: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-bottom: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-right: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-left: solid 1px #8EA9DB; font-size: 16px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: right; ">
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </form>
</body>
```

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: You can have one `body` tag per document and you certainly can't have a `body` tag as a child of `td`. Using valid HTML will get you a long way

Comment: @DanielPaul Man, I am very new in coding. That's why I need help. I will learn later. Can you please help now to fix my code? Thanks

Comment: Please help us to help you by cleaning up your code. Don't use inline styles, indent your code, only provide what is needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JonP I don't know how fix my code. Because I'm very new in coding. Can you please fix and post your full code? Thank you so much.

Comment: You are just starting out, now is the time to learn the basics.

Comment: @JonP I edited cleaned my code. Can you please recheck. Thanks again!

Comment: Are you doing this from a `file://` URL?  Annoyingly (and in my opinion, unwarranted), most browsers don't allow AJAX/fetch/xhr operations unless they're running from `http://` or `https://`.

Comment: ... If not, check the browser console for.errors. Google Drive/Sheets has some issues with these types of requests, see comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70179575/3196753

Answer (score 0):

Check this image you got CORS issue try in your code.

[image]

```js
function loadData() {
console.log('loadData');
  var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRxRr2GAVpZAtGlpG3vQVDIwqjHjWq3z2Y-NQOf5Tu9IoEZDRQAQwevq8LSIXgwcql6EMyINFf04Dp2/pub?gid=0&single=true&range=B2&output=csv";
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}






function loadData2() {
console.log('loadData2');
  var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRxRr2GAVpZAtGlpG3vQVDIwqjHjWq3z2Y-NQOf5Tu9IoEZDRQAQwevq8LSIXgwcql6EMyINFf04Dp2/pub?gid=0&single=true&range=B3&output=csv";
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function start(){
loadData();
loadData2();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>




<head>


</head>


<body onload="start()">
<form name="Cpro">
<table border="0" margin="0" padding="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr height="20"px; style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 61.539px; background-color:#D6DCE4; border-top: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-bottom: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-right: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-left: solid 1px #8EA9DB; font-size: 16px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: left; ">Test 1</td>


<td style="height:20px; width: 118.917px; background-color:#FFF2CC; border-top: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-bottom: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-right: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-left: solid 1px #8EA9DB; font-size: 16px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: right; ">
<div id="display"></div>

</td>


</tr>
<tr height=" 23.994px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 61.539px; background-color:#D6DCE4; border-top: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-bottom: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-right: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-left: solid 1px #8EA9DB; font-size: 16px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: left; ">Test 2</td>


<td style="height:20px; width: 118.917px; background-color:#FFF2CC; border-top: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-bottom: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-right: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-left: solid 1px #8EA9DB; font-size: 16px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: right; ">
<body onload='loadData2()'> 
<div id="display2"></div>
</td>


</tr>
<tr height=" 23.994px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 61.539px; background-color:#D6DCE4; border-top: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-bottom: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-right: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-left: solid 1px #8EA9DB; font-size: 16px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: left; ">Test 3</td>



<td style="height:20px; width: 118.917px; background-color:#FFF2CC; border-top: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-bottom: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-right: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-left: solid 1px #8EA9DB; font-size: 16px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: right; ">

</td>


</tr>
<tr height=" 23.994px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 61.539px; background-color:#D6DCE4; border-top: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-bottom: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-right: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-left: solid 1px #8EA9DB; font-size: 16px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: left; ">Test 4</td>


<td style="height:20px; width: 118.917px; background-color:#FFF2CC; border-top: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-bottom: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-right: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-left: solid 1px #8EA9DB; font-size: 16px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: right; ">

</td>
</tr>


<tr height=" 23.994px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 61.539px; background-color:#D6DCE4; border-top: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-bottom: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-right: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-left: solid 1px #8EA9DB; font-size: 16px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: left; ">Test 5</td>


<td style="height:20px; width: 118.917px; background-color:#FFF2CC; border-top: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-bottom: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-right: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-left: solid 1px #8EA9DB; font-size: 16px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: right; "> </td>

</tr>
<tr height=" 23.994px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 61.539px; background-color:#D6DCE4; border-top: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-bottom: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-right: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-left: solid 1px #8EA9DB; font-size: 16px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: left; ">Test 6</td>

<td style="height:20px; width: 118.917px; background-color:#FFF2CC; border-top: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-bottom: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-right: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-left: solid 1px #8EA9DB; font-size: 16px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: right; "></td>


</tr>
<tr height=" 23.994px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 61.539px; background-color:#D6DCE4; border-top: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-bottom: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-right: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-left: solid 1px #8EA9DB; font-size: 16px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: left; ">Test 7</td>


<td style="height:20px; width: 118.917px; background-color:#FFF2CC; border-top: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-bottom: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-right: solid 1px #8EA9DB; border-left: solid 1px #8EA9DB; font-size: 16px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: right; "></td>


</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tested your code. It's not working. Please check your code before posting. Because for the **Test 1**  field the value should display 10. But your code shows blank value for the Test 1 row.

Comment: @probika you got CORS Error that's why.
I called two function in one, i added image check in my answer

Comment: how to fix CORS issue? Can you please fix my code? I really have no idea how to fix it. Thanks in advance, man.

Comment: @probika If the resource you are requesting is not available for a  Cross Origin Request (CORS) there is nothing you can do to fix it, unless you control that source

Comment: @probika  check this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32897921/why-does-this-cors-request-to-a-google-drive-sheet-fail-in-firefox-works-in-c"